# Drupal 7 Views to Create Grid with Sub Grid

Tags: drupal, view

I want to create Drupal 7 Views something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| [ ]  |  Category Name                                                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| [+]  |  Computers & Software                                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| [+]  |  Computers & Hardware                                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| [-]  |  Laptops                                                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |  Company Name   |  Qty                                           |
       --------------------------------------------------------------------
       |  HP             |  1000                                          |
       --------------------------------------------------------------------
       |  DELL           |  2000                                          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It should be something like above.
When Click Category with [+] Sign It will be collapse and shown the sub-grid with Other Data like Company Name, Qty etc...

Is it possible in Drupal 7 with Views Module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need "Views fieldsets" module
http://drupal.org/project/views_fieldsets

i was not able get tutorilas for view fieldset but we used it our project for a similar situation.

But this is similar to what you require

see this post "http://drupal.org/node/1169632"

Comment: Any Example for Views Fieldsets which will help me for above given problem?